# Emacs region syntax highlighting

Tags: emacs

emacs users out there. I've been tinkering my emacs and encountered a small problem. I have global-font-lock-mode set to t, so i get nice syntax highlighting and it's working fine but when i select a region, highlighting is disabled. Is there a way to fix that? 
upd: The issue seems to appear with Solarized theme only. the zenburn theme works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solarized theme sets both the background colour and the foreground colour of the region face. The Zenburn theme only sets the background colour. You could create your own theme by modifying the Solarized theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are absolutely right. I just figured it out myself. The issue is solved.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Emacs 24.4 or a recent dev build? If so, the region now uses an overlay (it did not before). If you expect to see the region "on top of" other highlighting that uses an overlay, then the priority of the latter overlay must be lower than that of the region overlay.  So just changing the priority of one of the overlays should also fix the problem (again, if this is the cause).